# Execute C++ program when visitor enters website?

Tags: php, c++

Is it possible to run a C++ exe file when the user enters the website?

I mean, instead of `site/files/index.php` to have something like: `site/files/index.exe`, where `index.exe` is a C++ program.

I know it's possible to have a PHP file and use the exec function, but this wastes CPU cycles, is there any way to avoid calling a PHP script?

***edit**: to avoid misunderstanding: I expect the C++ program to run on the server and the console output to be shown on the browser's window.

Comment: CGI, FastCGI and SCGI.

Comment: Is there any drawback doing this? I mean, why people still use PHP if this thing exists? Only because PHP is faster to develop stuff?

Comment: Using PHP/Ruby/Python is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Luka Generating HTML in C++ gets tedious very quickly, and it's harder than you think to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some of PHP framework(lithify(li3.me) command line classes run with cron and so.